# Long-term storage of personal belongings?

Tags: home, storage, paper

So I have a lot of stuff and a lot of space in my parent's house and and obviously, I want to move some of my stuff to them (mostly paperwork, some packaging, catalogues, etc. - typical "hoarding" items).

What are some practices / what should I do to ...

- prevent stuff from degrading and
- prevent pests from spreading / catching on (moths, silverfish, ...)?

I thought about putting everything inside cardboard boxes, but this is obiously too little to keep moths etc. out. Should I put everything in vacuum bags? Is this enough? Should I put my stuff in the freezer overnight just in case to kill anything and everything? Should I put my stuff in an airtight box (plastic? metal?)? Should I fill said box with a noble gas so that no chemical reactions happen?

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Also, please move my question to another board if this is not the right board; however, I couldn't find a better fit.

Comment: Hi throwaway312, Welcome to Lifehacks StackExchange.

Comment: I'd try buying plastic boxes. You get them in various sizes and can mostly fit a lid on them, keeping unwanted things out

Comment: @CustomX I will probably go with plastic boxes, thanks for the advice. Do you know if I have to fear any chemical reactions from degrading plastic? Are theere any materials I should avoid? What if I indeed choose to fill an airtight plastic box with Argon?

Comment: @throwaway312, Not sure to be fair. You might not want to get the cheapest ones then, but as long as you keep them in a dry and ambient temperature, it should be ok.

Comment: In small areas, dryer sheets are a good defense against most pets; in larger areas, mothballs work (and do come in less "granny's attic" scented varieties).

Answer (score 2):

And whatever containers are used, add a bunch of those Silica Gel packets that absorb moisture, to each container.  You can probably buy them by the hundreds on Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

Use plastic boxes, since they come in many sizes. Place all your stuff in there.

If you have important documents or items, put them in a Ziploc bag so you can minimize water damage or if you want, you can put them in sheet protectors (for papers and documents).